# Translation for [Answer N here] placeholder is not used

Tags: bug, election, localization

It seems that the [translation for "Answer N here"](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=9750185b431789ebadcfb4e54ad80512) is not used on moderators election nominee page:

> [image: English "Answer N here" is shown on the Russian site instead of the linked Russian translation]